# Unable to resolve host name exception during sending http request using android volley through my app to AWS

Tags: android, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Unable to resolve host name exception during sending first  http request using android volley through my app to AWS(Amazon) where my Java Web Application is hosted. But when I request from mobile browser to the same link  then it respond and after this through app also it responds. Please help me out from this problem.#AWS#

Comment: Is it possible for you to check if your app is able to resolve DNS on its first request (the one that fails)? I am suspecting this could be because of DNS resolution delays.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I will research on your suggestion.